# Should I use effect sizes from multiple regression or raw correlations for meta-analyses?

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, meta-analysis, effect-size, systematic-review

I am conducting a meta-analysis and have encountered a study that provides both correlation coefficient and multiple regression statistics for the same effect.

Is using effect sizes from multiple regression better than raw correlation coefficients?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are all the multiple regression models the same or do they use different predictors?

Comment: They are different. They are hierarchical regression models, with the controlled variables entered first, followed by the variable of interest.

Comment: In that case I might avoid them in favour of the correlations as regressions based on different controlling variables are not strictly speaking comparable.

Comment: Ah I see, it makes perfect sense. So to be comparable in the meta-analysis, it's either to only include effect sizes that controlled for the same set of variables or to only include raw/uncontrolled effect sizes. Much appreciated!